# Selenium Wait Until For Queues

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a website that I want to automate with selenium. However, the website almost always has a queue where it has something such as this

[image]

In general, what would be the best way to use selenium to use the `WebDriverWait` ?

Currently, I have some thing that looks like this:

```
def wait_until(driver):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "checkout_email"))
        )
        return False
    except:
        return True

is_located = True
while is_located:
    is_located = wait_until(driver)
```

I would like to understand what is the idea behind such queues and whether there is generally anything in selenium that can help with increasing the probability of getting through such queues.

One idea I can think of is having multiple proxy-servers and running selenium through there, but aside from that is there any other neat tricks for such situations ?

Comment: I dont see a problem here. Your implementation is good. The test will wait until the queue page goes away and the checkout button is loaded.

Comment: Are you facing any constraints with _...some thing that..._ you are currently having the reason you want to change?

Comment: @DebanjanB what do you mean by constraints ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls constraints -> difficulties / issues / problems

Comment: @DebanjanB In terms of constraints, the goal is just to get through the queue as fast as possible with selenium. I guess I would like some advice to achieve this goal in addition to the usage of servers/proxies